# Angular2 form ng model ignored

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form below with ng model "user.account.emailFAKE" 
but if I print the form var I have this output:

> { "name": "fill name", "account": { "email": "email address",
>   "confirm": "confirm email" } }

The ngModel name is fully ignored?

```
 <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <label>
    <span>   Full name</span>
    <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Your full name"
    name="name"
    [ngModel]="user.name"
    #userName="ngModel"
    minlength="2"
    required>
 </label>
   <div *ngIf="userName.errors?.required  && userName.touched" class="error">
      Name is required
   </div>
  <div *ngIf="userName.errors?.minlength && userName.touched" class="error">
    Minimum of 2 characters
  </div>
 <div ngModelGroup="account" #userAccount="ngModelGroup">
   <label> <span>Email address</span>
     < input
       type="email"
       placeholder="Your email address"
       name="emailFAKE"
      [(ngModel)]="user.account.emailFAKE"
       required>
  </label>

  <label>
      <span>Confirm address</span>
    <input
      type="email"
      placeholder="Confirm your email address"
      name="confirm"
     [ngModel]="user.account.confirm"
     required>
  </label>
   <div *ngIf="userAccount.invalid && userAccount.touched" class="error">
    Both emails are required
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="f.invalid">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Why do I have to fill ngModel string in this situation if it's ignored?

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" 
 name="user.account.email"
[(ngModel)]="user.account.email" required>
```

Comment: You should be looking at `this.user`(which holds user) object instead of `form.values`.

Comment: @PankajParkar I't not using reactive forms, how this knows that I want to map it to this.user var on component?

Comment: In this situation why do I have to fill ngModel string if it's ignored? <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Your email address"
        name="user.account.email"
         [(ngModel)]="user.account.email"
        required>

Comment: Who says you need to use `[(ngModel)]` or `[ngModel]`? I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is here? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 for example if I want  two-way binding syntax. I'm doing this tutorial and I have with this doubth. url: https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven 

" name="name"  [(ngModel)]="user.name"> 2

Comment: Okay, and what is the problem? You can bind initial data to your form with ngModel. Still don't understand what the issue is? In what way is `ngModel` *ignored* like you state in the question? Could you make a plunker and point out what the issue is?

Comment: I was confused because of  name="name" and  [(ngModel)]="user.name" but i'm clarified now.

Answer (score 1):

In template-driven forms, Angular automatically creates a form structure for you behind the scenes. That form structure uses the `name` attribute to define the names of each control within its structure.

I don't understand why you are not seeing:

```
{ 
  "name": "fill name", 
  "account": { "emailFAKE": "email address", "confirm": "confirm email" } 
 }
```

Is it possible you have not saved those changes? Or that the old version is cached?

And the values for each of the controls *should* be the value as defined by the `ngModel`. Maybe post your component code as well so we can see what's going on there?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. with name="emailFAKE" e see that reflected on json. The initial html was changed. I was just confused why I have to fill [(ngModel)]="user.account.emailFAKE"
if there is the property name. But I decided to use reactive forms, i find them much more simple and practicle.